# como renderizar um JSON no reactJS

Tags: json, node.js, react, axios, render

estou começando a aprender react e quero conectar com um server nodeJS
ele esta retornando um JSON `[{nome:"joão",sobre:"victor"}]`

então no react:

```
class Page extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)     
        Axios.get("/teste").then((response)=>{
            this.resposta=response;
            this.string=this.resposta.data[0].nome
            console.log(this.string)
        })

    }
```

mas não consigo renderizar nem o return nem o string,só aparece no console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, Joao,

Creio que o erro seja na declaração da função.
Se não me engano, voce não pode criar o procedimento no constructor.

Você deve usar a função padrão do react `componentDidMount()` ou `componentWillMount()`.

Assim deve funcionar:

```
class Page extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios
            .get("/teste/")
            .then((response) => {
                this.resposta=response;
                console.log(this.resposta)
                this.string=this.resposta.data[0].nome
                console.log(this.string)
            })
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

O que eu fiz:
Mudei a identação do procedimento do axios para facilitar o entendimento;
Coloquei o procedimento de busca na funcao componentDidMount(), que é automaticamente executada logo após o render da página;
Criei 3 console.log, um que retorna a resposta, outro que retorna a string e outro que retorna o erro. Se você nao receber no console o this.resposta, vai saber que o erro está acontecendo antes de chegar nessa parte, se receber o this.resposta e não receber o this.string, o erro está entre essas duas linhas, aí volta aqui para te ajudarmos.
Se houver qualquer erro na conexão, o axios faz o que está em `.catch`. Nesse caso, mostra o erro no console, aí voce pode ler e ver se consegue descobrir o erro, ou posta aqui para nós.

O conteudo da sua pagina vai ficar entre os divs que existem no render.

Tenho quase certeza que o erro era a posição do procedimento.

Testa lá e responde aqui se deu certo.

Boa sorte!

Comment: deu certo aparecer no console,mas não aparece na pagina

Comment: estou tentando mandar o string no render,mas ele não aparece

Comment: @joão.victor_a. como está a sintaxe no render? O certo seria ter "{this.string}" (sem aspas). Se não der certo, o que eu faria é armazenar o nome em um state "nome". Tente isso e fala pra gente se deu certo.